# how to upload file to subfolder in bucket in google cloud storage using php

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

i want to upload file to subfolder in bucket how can i do that can anyone please help me to do that

am able to uplaod to bucket but unable to upload to subfolder in bucket

my bucket name is fb-uploads

subfolder is china

below is my code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

 $storage = new StorageClient([ 'keyFilePath' => 'facebooth_bucket.json']);
 $bucketName = 'fb-uploads';

$uploadDocument = isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) ? $_FILES['uploaded_file'] : '';

$uploaddir = "uploads/";

if (isset($uploadDocument['name']) && !empty($uploadDocument['name'])) {

                $uploadFileName = str_replace(" ","_",basename($uploadDocument['name']));

                $ext = pathinfo($uploadFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $fileName = str_replace("." . $ext, "", $uploadFileName);


                $uploadFileName = $fileName . "_" . date('his') . '.' . $ext;

                $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $uploadFileName;
                // die($uploadfile);

                if (move_uploaded_file($uploadDocument['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

                    if(file_exists($uploadfile)) {
                        try {
                                $objectName = $uploadFileName;

                                $file = fopen($uploadfile, 'r');
                                $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
                                $object = $bucket->upload('/china/'.$uploadfile, [
                                    'name' => $objectName
                                ]);
                                printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($uploadFileName), $bucketName, $objectName);
                            // require_once __DIR__ . "/google_storage/vendor/autoload.php";
                            // $storage = new StorageClient([
                            //     'keyFilePath' => '/var/www/html/crewbies/upload_testing/google_storage/key/facebooth_bucket.json'
                            // ]);
                            // $bucket =  $storage->bucket('fb-uploads');
                            // $bucket->upload(
                            //     fopen('/china/$uploadfile', 'r')
                            // );
                        }
                        catch(Exception $e) {
                            $err = $e->getMessage();
                            print_r($err);
                            die('heee');
                        }

                    }

                }


            }

            ?>


<html>
   <body>

      <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
         <input type="submit"/>
      </form>

   </body>
</html>
```

i want to upload file to subfolder in bucket how can i do that can anyone please help me to do that

Comment: Please read [documentation how subfolders work](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork). 
The object gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt is just an object that happens to have "/" characters in its name. There is no "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name.

Comment: I understand that your object looks like that: "/china/file-name.xxx" but should be "china/file-name.xxx" ?

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation how subfolders work.](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/HowSubdirectoriesWork)

The object gs://your-bucket/abc/def.txt is just an object that happens to have "/" characters in its name.

There is no "abc" directory; just a single object with the given name.

I understand that your object looks like that:

`"/china/file-name.xxx"`

but should be

`"china/file-name.xxx"`